# d3 selecting .attr('x1') returns r.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to track position of a line by `xScale`. So as soon as `x1` becomes  `xScale1.range()[1]` it reaches its final position and should change a colour. In the DOM line has x1 attribute with a certain value of 500. What am I doing wrong?

```
g1.append('line')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .style('stroke', 'white')
  .attr('x1', xScale1.range()[0] + 100)
  .attr('x2', xScale1.range()[0] + 100)
  .attr('y1', yScale1.range()[0])
  .attr('y2', yScale1.range()[1])
  .transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr('x1', xScale1.range()[1])
  .attr('x2', xScale1.range()[1])
  .style('stroke', function (d) {
    changeColour();
  })
  
function changeColour(d) {
  if (d3.select(this).attr('x1') === xScale1.range()[1]){
    return 'red';
  };
}
```

Comment: And how is `changeColour` called?

Comment: Thanks,I've edited my question but it doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: because look at `console.log(this);`

Comment: It can be just `.style('stroke', changeColour)`. Way easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` no longer points to the selection object, but instead to the local function scope. By nesting the functions, you've changed that value. You can easily avoid this by passin g `this` as an argument to `changeColour`.

```
function change colour(element)
```

```
change colour(this)
```